# What do you call someone who excels at setting and disarming traps?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Alright, I'm going to just start by saying there probably isnt an equivalent for this, but here is pretty much my line of thought. If you need someone to unlock a door for you, you call a 'locksmith'. Now, suppose you needed someone to disarm or even set traps for you, whether it is for animal hunting, or pest control, you would call a _______?

Words that I can think of: "Hunter", "Trapper".

Is there a professional ***single word*** name for people like this? *Even an archaic one*?

Example sentence: ***"We needed to trick the dragon, so xxx, an experienced ______, 
set out to rig a trap in the next room."***

Comment: @Cascabel Sapper is certainly one I've never heard of. I wonder if anyone can think of more.

Comment: @Cascabel I just came across "Engineer" as a possible candidate, too.

Comment: @Krythic Only in an obsolete sense, unless you're including all the words that just mean *builder of devices*.

Comment: One famous author used ___burglar___.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about animals and not all forms of traps employed against humans, you already answered your question with the most common word:

## trapper

although @Traktor53 pointed out that specialists will call themselves ***X*-catchers**. (It's got a more positive spin on it than its synonyms *X*-trapper and *X*-hunter, since an *X*-hunter may have gone their entire life without, y'know, actually catching an *X* at all and an *X*-trapper's prey may have always escaped after being trapped.) If you want to coin your own word but want it to have some connection to English etymology, there's

- **trapsmith** (who would build traps to sell to other people but not use them herself),
- **engineer** (from an obsolete sense of [*engine* as "An instance of artful trickery"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62223#eid5409851)), which could be distinguished by the obsolete or Scottish spelling [*ingineer*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95789),
- **awaiter** (from [*await*, obs., "An ambush, a trap, a plot"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13857)),
- **fanger** (from [*fang*, arch., "To grasp, to catch; to trap"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68057)),
- **stamper** or [**stalper**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188867) (from [*stamp*, dial., "A trap"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188921)),
- **illaqueator** (from Latin *illaqueare*, "To ensnare"), esp. with rope traps,
- **swarler** or [**swarrer**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195476) (from [*swarl*, "To trap"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195491)),
- **swiker** (from [*swike*, obs., "A trick; a trap"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195812)),
- **braker**, [**briker**, or **bryker**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23326) (from [*brake*, obs., "A trap"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22563)), and
- [**panter**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136989) or **panther** (orig. from Latin *panthera*, "A net for catching birds", but with a wider sense in English inclusive of treasonous plots).

There are some others even more misleading than *engineer* and *braker*, like *lacer*, *latcher*, *leasher*, [*puppy-snatcher*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154804#eid27516453), *snarler*, *wirer*, based on obsolete senses of those words. Again, you could create specialist terms like *hutcher* (an employer of [*hutches* or "box-traps"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89745)), *pitcher* and [*picher*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/238067) (a setter of [*pitches* or "fishtraps"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144681#eid29843911)), *gnarer* (a setter of [choking traps](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79444)), *shraper* (a setter of [food-lure traps](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178795)), and *grinner* or [*graner*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/80719) (an employer of [*grins* or "rope-and-noose foot-traps"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81512)). The last could also be known as a [*swickler*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195780), after the noose itself. 'Kill-'em-all-and-let-God-sort-'em-out' is an **exterminator**.

As far as someone able to set mantraps, well, there is [**man-catcher**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113198#eid38354980) (further buttressing Traktor's point) but for the most part people are a complicated lot and there are hordes of different skill-sets involving everything from *rangers* and *commandos* acting as *ambushers* to *demolition experts* variously blowing things up or stopping them from doing so to *seductresses* playing the part of a *honeypot*.

**Side point**: [*squire-trap*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/188426#eid21096850) for a bog or other soft piece of ground to catch the English landed gentry as they attempt to bother foxes is delightful and needs more usage.

Comment: "Trapsmith" doesn't appear to be a word in Google. Do you have any sources to support that one?

Comment: [Sure](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182645#eid22067144).

Comment: Your link just takes me to the main page of that site, asking me to login.

Comment: @Krythic The link is fine. There are plenty of institutions who list their OED access on the web but, if you can't be bothered, you can review what I already posted. It's not about current usage but coining your own word. The 'correct' answer remains *trapper* for animals, *-catcher* for specialists, and a whole range of things for humans.

Answer (score 1):

See if **snarer** holds some value. It is defined [here at vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/snarer) as

> someone who sets snares for birds or small animals.

Though a dragon is huge, I'm sure a snarer will figure something out. Why not, I mean he is just setting trap for a big bird that breathes fire and has an indestructible integument.

Comment: Though it sets up a nice resonance with *sneering* in the face of danger, [*snares* are definitionally too small even for large birds](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183047), let alone enormous indestructible fire-breathing crustaceans from the Paleolithic era.

Answer (score 1):

"catcher" could be an alternative to "trapper" or "hunter" and, using "rat-catcher" as the basis of its etymology, could be extended to describe an experienced "dragon-catcher".

> catcher: A person or thing that catches something. ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catcher))
>
> rat-catcher: (medieval profession) A person who  practices catching rats ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rat-catcher), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat-catcher), the Concise Oxford Dictionary, or do a web search for "profession rat catcher").)

In common with "hunter" and "trapper" you may need to assume that catchers are expert in dismantling their own traps: I doubt there will be a "dragon trap disposal expert" professional position unless held by a dragon :-)

Comment: I don't know. Presumably the dragons need to hire a non-dragon to disarm the dragon traps. Not sure how good the long-term prospects of such a job are, though, given the inherent difficulty when it comes time to be paid...

Comment: What does O.E.D. stand for?

Comment: @Clare O.E.D. stands for [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/). They have a link to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) which has links to free online versions of their Spanish and English dictionaries.

Comment: Okay, but when you quote the free online Oxford dictionary, you are not quoting the *Oxford English Dictionary*. The popular abbreviation for what you are quoting is the ODO (Oxford Dictionary online). You should edit your answer to include the proper abbreviation.

Comment: For example, "A person or thing that catches something" does not appear in the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED). It appears in the ODO.

Comment: @Clare Thanks. The Concise Oxford dictionary, based on the Oxford English Dictionary,  hard copy 6th Edition 1976 defines rat-catcher, but only has a separate entry for "catcher" as being a base-ball catcher.  Updated accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

> ### [nimrod](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nimrod)
>
> (noun)
>
> ***A skilful hunter.***
>
> *‘nimrods take to the field after everything from prairie dogs to
>   grizzly bears’*
>
> ([OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nimrod))
>
> ***Origin***
>
> Late 16th century: from Hebrew Nimrōḏ, the name of the great-grandson
>   of Noah, known for his skill as a hunter (see Gen. 10:8-9).

*From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Nimrod) Dictionary:*

> ### Definition of [Nimrod](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Nimrod)
>
> 1
>       :  *a descendant of Ham represented in Genesis as a mighty hunter and a king of Shinar*
>
> 2    *not capitalized* :  hunter
>
> 3    *not capitalized*, slang :  idiot, jerk
>
> ### Did You Know?
>
> Nimrod is described in Genesis as "the first on earth to be a mighty
>   man" and "a mighty hunter before the Lord." It's easy to see how
>   people made the leap from one mighty hunter in the Bible to calling
>   any hunter a nimrod. A lesser-known fact is that nimrod has seen some
>   use in English as a noun meaning "tyrant" (apparently, the mighty
>   Nimrod was not reputed to be an especially benevolent king), although
>   that sense is now essentially obsolete. The legendary Nimrod is also
>   sometimes associated with the attempt to build the Tower of Babel.
>   Because the tower resulted in the wrath of the Lord and proved a
>   disastrous idea, nimrod is sometimes used with yet another meaning: "a
>   stupid person."

***From [Online Etymology Dictionary:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nimrod)***

> "great hunter," 1712, a reference to the biblical son of Cush,
>   referred to (Genesis x.8-9) as "a mighty hunter before the Lord." It
>   came to mean "geek, klutz" by 1983 in teenager slang, for unknown
>   reasons. (Amateur theories include its occasional use in "Bugs Bunny"
>   cartoon episodes featuring rabbit-hunting Elmer Fudd as a foil; its
>   possible ironic use, among hunters, for a clumsy member of their
>   fraternity; or a stereotype of deer hunters by the non-hunting
>   population in the U.S.

Comment: Thank you for that word, but as your link already told you it has meant *an idiot* since the 20th century to most of the world's English-speakers. The free version of the entry doesn't note this but [the real *OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127171) even the hunting sense is *frequently ironic*. Nimrod wasn't a good figure in the Old Testament, so even the people who catch the hunting allusion aren't going to look on him very kindly.

Comment: Now, that said, if @Krythic wanted to *make fun of* a skillful hunter, yes 'Nimrod' is the perfect word.

Comment: Yes, it has a secondary meaning: (North American informal) An inept person.

Comment: First, that's the primary meaning to most of the world's English speakers, as already mentioned. It's only listed where it is because *Oxford Dictionaries* (!= *OED*) is primarily British English. Second, as already mentioned, even the hunting sense is glossed by the actual *OED* as *frequently ironic*: that is, it is much more often used mockingly of people who pompously presume to be better hunters than they actually are than for actual good hunters.

Comment: Again, thank you for the word, but it has some serious problems.

Comment: @lly In the posters defense, I did say "even an archaic one", so his suggestion is not technically out of bounds.

Comment: The OP is looking for **even an archaic word!**